# Is it legit? https://code.visualstudio.com redirected me to: http://az764295.vo.msecnd.net when downloading

Tags: macos, visual-studio, redirect, visual-studio-code, installation

I've downloaded Visual Studio Code from https://code.visualstudio.com but it says that it is downloaded from: `http://az764295.vo.msecnd.net`. Sorry (the popup is in czech) but Is it legit?

**Translation:** "Visual studio code" is downloaded from the internet Do you want to open it?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you visited https://code.visualstudio.com, that is official website, then it is obviously legit.

Answer (score 6):

The Visual Studio Code web site lists common hostnames for auto-update.  The site az764295.vo.msecnd.net is one of those listed:

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/network

I had an similar certificate issue that directed me to your question.